# How to pipe large file into mongodb using gridfsbucket, when receiving file in chunks?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am using nodejs, mongodb, and gridfsbucket.

I am receiving a file into my server in 255 byte chunks, the files can be extremely large so creating a variable to store the chunks and then piping that into mongo using gridfsbucket is not a viable option.

Currently I have a working method of temporarily storing the file on disk and then piping that into mongo. This actually works pretty well, the only problem is I don't want to temporarily store the data before streaming into mongo using gridfsbucket.

Does anyone know how to take those chunks as they are coming into my server and immediately stream them into mongo using gridfsbucket? I am thinking that I would need to open the pipe and then constantly stream the chunks into the pipe, but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

This is my current code for storing to the disk:

```
fs.appendFileSync(this.tempFileName, Buffer.from(this.currfile.currdatachunk));
this.currfile.filename = this.currfile.filename.replace(")", Date.now() + ")");
var fileName = decodeURI(this.currfile.filename.replace("$(", "").replace(")", ""));
 fileName = encodeURI(fileName);
 var self = this;
 var gb = new GridFSBucket(mongoCacheDb, { bucketName: this.cacheCollection });
 var uploadStream = gb.openUploadStream(fileName);

 uploadStream.options.metadata = {
     'url': "/getFile/" + fileName,
     'id': uploadStream.id
 }

 uploadStream.once("finish", function uploadStream_onceFinish() {
                        if (this.length > 0) {
                            var ms = new Message();
                            ms.data = self.cacheCollection + "/" + self.currfile.filename;
                            ms.datatype = "URL";
                            ms.hasdata = "yes";
                            ms.haserrors = "no";
                            ms.type = "APPXLOADURL";
                            sendMessage(ws, ms);

                            /*Send response to server indicating file receipt*/
                            var nameAB = Buffer.from(self.currfile.filename);
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(hton32(nameAB.length)));
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(nameAB));
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from([3, 1]));
                            console.log("Finished: " + Date.now());
                        } else {
                            var nameAB = Buffer.from(self.currfile.filename);
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(hton32(nameAB.length)));
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(nameAB));
                            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from([0, 0]));
                        }
                        fs.unlinkSync(self.tempFileName);
                    });
                    fs.createReadStream(this.tempFileName).pipe(uploadStream);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have waited another day. Finally wrapped my head around it and stopped overthinking it. I created the pipe on the first run and then just pushed the buffered chunks into the pipe as they were received. Code is below:

```
if (this.chunksReceived == 0) {
    this.rStream = new Readable({ read(size) { } });

    this.currfile.filename = this.currfile.filename.replace(")", Date.now() + ")");
    var fileName = decodeURI(this.currfile.filename.replace("$(", "").replace(")", ""));
    fileName = encodeURI(fileName);
    var self = this;
    var gb = new GridFSBucket(mongoCacheDb, { bucketName: this.cacheCollection });
    this.uploadStream = gb.openUploadStream(fileName);

    this.uploadStream.options.metadata = {
        'url': "/getFile/" + fileName,
        'id': this.uploadStream.id
    }

    this.uploadStream.once("finish", function uploadStream_onceFinish() {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            var ms = new Message();
            ms.data = self.cacheCollection + "/" + self.currfile.filename;
            ms.datatype = "URL";
            ms.hasdata = "yes";
            ms.haserrors = "no";
            ms.type = "APPXLOADURL";
            sendMessage(ws, ms);

            /*Send response to server indicating file receipt*/
            var nameAB = Buffer.from(self.currfile.filename);
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(hton32(nameAB.length)));
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(nameAB));
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from([3, 1]));
            console.log("Finished: " + Date.now());
        } else {
            var nameAB = Buffer.from(self.currfile.filename);
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(hton32(nameAB.length)));
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from(nameAB));
            self.clientsocket.write(Buffer.from([0, 0]));
        }
    });

    this.rStream.pipe(this.uploadStream);
}
this.rStream.push(Buffer.from(this.currfile.currdatachunk));
this.chunksReceived++;
```